# Knex - Postgres RDS not able to use SSL

Tags: knex.js, node-postgres

I am trying to use ssl in knex for postgres.
I downloaded RDS CA's certificate from here https://truststore.pki.rds.amazonaws.com/ap-south-1/ap-south-1-bundle.pem
I set up the knex config as follows

```
const config: Knex.Config = {
        client: 'pg',
        connection: {
            host: process.env.HOST,
            user: process.env.USERNAME,
            password: process.env.PASSWORD,
            database: process.env.DB,
            ssl: {
                ca: require('fs').readFileSync(__dirname + '/rds-ca.pem'),
                maxVersion: 'TLSv1.2',
            }
        },
        pool: { min: 2, max: 50, idleTimeoutMillis: 300000 },
        debug: true
    }
```

I can log the result of require('fs').readFileSync(__dirname + '/rds-ca.pem'), so no issue of file not present
I have set DEBUG=knex:* to see if knex using ssl

When i do any query, it works fine , i can see knex:client/query/binding logs but I cannot see ssl log as if telling knex is using ssl

How can I resolve this issue ?